# Program goes into infinite loop, But if removed some functions or lines, it works

Tags: c++, loops

A basic student database using classes, I accept
name,
roll number, and
sgpa(cgpa equivalent but out of 10).
I used while loop, and switch case,but if the code for sgpa validation, and code for displaying all students with same sgpa is removed, the program works neatly, but if not, the program goes into continuous loop, the while loop inside the main, as it accepts the options itself and keeps doing it.

The code fails when i accept the sgpa(while taking the student data) or call the displaySGPA fucntion(option 3)

```
 int totalStudents=0;


class database{
  float sgpa;
  int roll;
  string name;

  public:
    void getSGPA();
    void getData(database []);
    friend void displaySGPA(int,database []);
};
    //Display Students with same SGPA
void displaySGPA(int temp,database students[]){
  int i,sameSGPA=0;
  for(i=0;i<totalStudents;i++){
    if(students[i].sgpa==temp){
      sameSGPA+=1;
    }
  }
  if(sameSGPA>1){
    cout<<"\nStudents with SGPA "<<temp<<"."<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<totalStudents;i++){
      if(students[i].sgpa==temp){
        cout<<" "<<students[i].roll<<"  "<<students[i].name;
      }
    }
  }

  else if(sameSGPA==1){
    cout<<"Only one student with the SGPA , "<<temp<<". :"<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<totalStudents;i++){
      if(students[i].sgpa==temp){
        cout<<" "<<students[i].roll<<"  "<<students[i].name;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  else{
    cout<<"No Student with given SGPA."<<endl;
  }
  
}
void database :: getData(database students []){  
  cout<<"\nEnter Name         : ";
  cin>>name;
  cout<<"Enter Roll. ";
  cin>>roll;
  getSGPA();
}

//SGPA validation
void database :: getSGPA(){
  int x=1,temp;
  while(x==1){
    cout<<"Enter SGPA         : ";
    cin>>temp;
    if(temp<=10){
      sgpa=temp;
      break;
    }
    else{
      cout<<"Please enter a valid SGPA.";
    }
  }
}

//main Loop
int main() {
  int x,temp;
  database students[50];
  while (x!=5){
    cout<<"\n1.Enter a New Student.\n3.Display students with same SGPA.\n5.Exit.\n\nYour Choice  :  ";
    cin>>x;
    switch(x){
      case 1:
        students[totalStudents].getData(students);
        totalStudents++;
        break;
      case 3:
        cout<<"\nEnter the SGPA.";
        cin>>temp;
        displaySGPA(temp,students);
        break;
      case 5:
        cout<<"Exiting the program.....";
        break;
      default:
        cout<<"Please select a valid option."<<endl;    
    }


  }
  
}
```

Comment: Can you please cut this down to only the relevant bits of code?

Comment: Possibly because you have `while(x==1)`, but never change the value of `x` in the loop.

Comment: @ChrisMM there is a break though

Comment: @user253751, I edited to say "possibly" ... I don't know what inputs its being given.

Comment: @ChrisMM did it, cut it down to the main part affecting the errors.

Comment: Your code won't compile. It's good that you trimmed it down and it also needs to compile. For example, totalStudents is not established.

Comment: what is totalStudents variable in displaySGPA function?

Comment: @ChungHuang edited the needed bits.

Comment: What's wrong in your code, the program works fine.

Comment: You may want to read these two links: 1. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) 2. [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Please post the results of your debugging session, and indicate where the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the bug, it was a type conversion bug, i was accepting a float value but passing it as a int,just worked, don't know why.But thanks for each comment and suggestion.